# PySpark Error: " An error occurred while calling o31.parseDataType"

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load the .gz file with pySpark, but getting this error.
My python code is:

```
schema_daily = StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("date", DataType(), True),
    StructField("element", StringType(), True),
    StructField("value", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("measurement flag", StringType(), True),
    StructField("quality flag", StringType(), True),
    StructField("source flag", StringType(), True),
    StructField("observation time", TimestampType(), True),
])
daily = (
    spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "false")
    .option("inferSchema", "false")
    .schema(schema_daily)
    .load("hdfs:///data/ghcnd/daily/1763.csv.gz")
)
daily.cache()
daily.show()
```

The file are stored as:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   8 hadoop supergroup  196551118 2019-03-17 21:26 /data/ghcnd/daily/2013.csv.gz
-rwxr-xr-x   8 hadoop supergroup  193121272 2019-03-17 21:26 /data/ghcnd/daily/2014.csv.gz
-rwxr-xr-x   8 hadoop supergroup  196007583 2019-03-17 21:26 /data/ghcnd/daily/2015.csv.gz
-rwxr-xr-x   8 hadoop supergroup  194390036 2019-03-17 21:27 /data/ghcnd/daily/2016.csv.gz
-rwxr-xr-x   8 hadoop supergroup  125257391 2019-03-17 21:27 /data/ghcnd/daily/2017.csv.gz
```

Looks like it complains the failure of converting JSON string to a data type, not sure it is related to the file type or not?

The full error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o31.parseDataType.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to convert the JSON string 'data' to a data type.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType$$anonfun$nameToType$1.apply(DataType.scala:142)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType$$anonfun$nameToType$1.apply(DataType.scala:142)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone in interested, I had the same error and the problem was that one of the files I was reading did not comply the schema. The mismatch was caused by a column in different order. The pyspark error is not very helpful, but you can check in the spark log. Mine was ike this:

```
19/08/19 19:40:49 WARN CSVDataSource: CSV header does not conform to the schema.
Header: col1, col2, col4, col3
Schema: col1, col2, col3, col4
Expected: col3 but found: col4
```

Answer (score 1):

Anne, I see you have used the Scala way of reading the schema. I'm sure there are other developers who face the same error, that's why I decided to answer this question even though it's an old question. Another problem is that you have a DateType() in your schema, but you didn't give it any format when you load the data.

```
spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "false")
    .option("inferSchema", "false")
    .schema(schema_daily)  # This is not how you do it in Python. This is the Scala way
    .load("hdfs:///data/ghcnd/daily/1763.csv.gz")
```

So this is how you should do it:

```
spark.read.format("csv")
     .option("header", "true")
     .option("inferSchema", "false")
     .option('dateFormat', ' <the format of your date> ')  # this is missing in your read function. 
     .schema=schema_daily  # this line has been changed
```

Another way (or a better way):

```
spark.read.option('dateFormat', ' <the format of your date> ').csv(
    header=True,
    schema=schema_daily
)
```

In your answer, you just removed the schema which is not solving the error.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is resolved by

```
raw_daily = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("hdfs:///data/ghcnd/daily/1800.csv.gz")
```